# Flex 4 component is created before dataprovider gets data

Tags: list, apache-flex, flex4, adobe, flex3

I have a custom component (List) which gets the dataprovider from external xml which calls a service again.Dataprovider is set to custom list by ID.

For the first time when screen loads the list is generated with data but later after if I refresh the screen the list is loaded with empty because list is getting created before dataprovider gets values from xml and service.

Every time if I run in debug mode I will get the list generated as I will wait till dataprovider gets data..but if I run in normal mode I could see empty list some times.

Comment: Give list dataprovider dynamic at runtime when you result get.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Binding the Dataprovider to the list. So even if it is updated late it will automatically update the list.

You can use metadata tag something like:

```
 [Bindable]
private var arrayCollection:ArrayCollection;
```

and update the 'arrayCollection' when you get data dynamically.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am doing migration from flex 3.5 to flex 4.1. If compiler was set to 3.5 then I have no issues.If I change compiler to 4.1 then list sometimes appear and sometimes doesn't. If i keep thread.sleep(100) in my java class then list will appear all the time. Also I found that after flex initialization the loading bar fills if it take time to load UI list appear..if loading bar fills and immediately UI appears list doesn't appear. Don't know why this is happening.

Comment: I think it is not a logical issue. It may be something related to FLEX SDKs you are switching. And also that Initialization progress bar fills immediately may be because of 'caching'. I am just guessing. ALL THE BEST.

Comment: is there anything to do in services-config.xml and channel polling?

Answer (score 0):

The data binding could be the solution for your problem.
Other way could be set the dataprovider of the list when the service gets the result
- Call the service
- The service obtains the data
- list.dataProvider = result of the service

Anyway, data binding seems the best solution

```
[Bindable]
private var arrayCollection:ArrayCollection;

<s:List dataProvider="{arrayCollection}" ....
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.i tried all these but didn't worked.my issue is few times like 5% probability list is loaded.list will load once if i restart server and later it will not load.i think issue with java flex interaction. The list is loading all the times if i keep thread.sleep(100)  in javaclass after we get result from service.But i shouldnot use sleep.Any ideas on this?

Comment: Maybe you could show some code.  Maybe you are not waiting to have the data from the server.

Comment: code is the same like how you represented above.The same works for other components like datagrid,checkbox array,radiobuttongroup,labels...but for list it's not happening.Is there anything to do in channel polling and services-config.xml ? can we add some delay for processing or remove caching?